# Invalid method when method is valid

Tags: function, lua

I have just started a new version of my Crysis Wars Server Side Modification called InfinityX. For better management, I have put the functions inside tables as it looks neater and I can group functions together (like Core.PlayerHandle:GetIp(player)), but I have ran into a problem.
The problem is that the specified method to get the players' name, `player:GetName()` is being seen as an invalid method, when the method actually is completely valid.

I would like to know if using the below structure is causing a problem and if so, how to fix it. This is the first time I've used this structure for functions, but it is already proving easier than the old method I was using.

*The Code:*

```
Event = 
{
    PlayerConnect = function(player)
        Msg.All:CenteredConsole("$4Event$8 (Connect)$9: $3"..player:GetName().." on channel "..player.actor:GetChannel());
        System.LogAlways(Default.Tag.."Incoming Connect on Channel "..player.actor:GetChannel());
        Event:Log("Connect", player);
    end;
};
```

*The below code works when I bypass the function and put the code directly where it's needed:*

```
Msg.All:CenteredConsole("$4Event$8 (Connect)$9: $3"..player:GetName().." on channel "..player.actor:GetChannel());

System.LogAlways(Default.Tag.."Incoming Connect on Channel "..player.actor:GetChannel());
```

*The Error:*

[Warning] [Lua Error] infinityx/main/core.events.lua:23: attempt to call method 'GetName' (a nil value)

> PlayerConnect, (infinityx/main/core.events.lua: 23)
>   ConnectScript, (infinityx/main/core.main.lua: 52)
>   OnClientEnteredGame, (scripts/gamerules/instantaction.lua: 511)
>   (null) (scripts/gamerules/teaminstantaction.lua: 520)

Any clarification would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as PlayerConnect is inside the table Event, and you are calling with a ":", add self as first arg in the function, like:

```
PlayerConnect = function(self, player)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `player` in the first block of code is not the same as `player` in the second block of code. The problem must be that the caller of `Event.PlayerConnect` is not passing the same value.

To test that your `Event.PlayerConnect` function works, try this in the same place as your second block of code:

```
Event.PlayerConnect(player)
```

That should work as you expect.

So, the problem comes down to how `Event.PlayerConnect` is called without the second block of code. I'm not familiar with that game engine so I don't know how it is done. Perhaps reviewing the documentation and/or debugging that area would help. If you `print(player)` or call the equivalent log function in both cases, you should see they are different. If you can't run in a debugger, you can still get a stack trace with `print(debug.traceback("Accessing player, who's value is: "..player))`. If there is indeed some kind of table-based `player` object in both cases, you can try comparing their fields to see how they are different. You might need to write a simple dumping function to help with that.

Comment: The two 'player' values are the same. They're called master function and should not have any differences. I've just done further testing and it appears that 'player' has nothing in it. However if 'player' was empty, the client wouldn't have any name. I'm going to try again using a clean set of files to see if something in here has gone wrong.